# Google Auth ux_mode="redirect" appending # to the redirect_uri. Is there any way to remove that # appended to redirect_uri

Tags: angular, angular-routing, google-authentication

I am redirecting to Google Auth on button Click and initialized it as follows.

```
this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'client_id',
        client_secret: 'client_secret',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        ux_mode: 'redirect',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard'
      });
```

Now after successful authentication it is being redirected to dashboard but the url is as follows.

```
http://localhost:4200/dashboard#scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20openid%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImNmMDIyYTQ5ZTk3ODYxNDhhZDBlMzc5Y2M4NTQ4NDRlMzZjM2VkYzEiLCJ0eXAiOiE4NjQyMDYsImV4cCI6MTU1MTg2NzgwNiwianRpIjoiY2FjMzRkNmM3NGU2Y2MwYjliMDNhOTZiMDk1NmI0OTc5YjQ5MWE0OSJ9.QY29fd6-T6DzbMqEjzuvmW63NhE_tFbGeP9inFw-Xb3MSWnmNXO25WSwqG43JYN-Nv_68S3eDoqV8Y9iYtVOkjupxgcmXMRAZRj-zl9EkTeSbNRM8YIRIhRHhInSszCl-cG76bXHh6xUlvIUoIjFxhm5skPsN0Z_c1YDwKB2FnbljmyyAcfu6ASHRFTvve-B7Y1X9O1SAZ-6StTXDMWlLnh3TFA_MrRKGQJZG6phyzeJlHVMkN-Ivn81N_9uKmL4UFkz6di3nd3-t1J0iw5pJW63qL1GQWD9u1e8YT05vf7sbNDai5tGWD-5MDwQZgeHMIOnNvOUgKQiilGYgdSnKw&login_hint=AJDLj6JUa8yxXrhHdWRHIV0S13cAFV_867LrZxQpJZmuFYewge0uyMoVtdn1_CuHT2He1b26-i8q7hNkWTlekVeX8ZX-LU4VXg
```

Now I have to extract access token from this URL.
I have written queryMap in angular to extract but it doesn't work because the URL has # in it. Would anyone give me an idea of how to achieve this? 
Thanks In advance